# search a column of strings above the current row to see if current column string has been used

Tags: excel-formula

search a column of strings above the current row to see if current column string has been used. if not used then I will use it in  a cell to display a dollar amount using this code

```
=CONCATENATE(C3,"",TEXT(SUMIF($C$3:C102,C3,F$3:F$101),"$0.0"),0)
```

C column is a list of providers that have repeating values

F column is a list of charges each provider might have multiple entries.

I am trying to create a list in a separate columns to display total charges by provider without listing duplicate providers

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your formula in a Countif where the first cell of the range is an absolute reference, and the last cell of the range is a relative reference, like this, starting in row 3 and copied down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$3:C3,C3)=1,CONCATENATE(C3,"",TEXT(SUMIF($C$3:C102,C3,F$3:F$101),"$0.0"),0),"")
```

[image]

Comment: teylyn Thank you!